# Can't execute .click() in my code after ajax loads content I want to click on

Tags: javascript, ajax, userscripts

I'm writing a user script which will .click() on a button that calls an Ajax update and after it loads I need to .click() on a button that was loaded by this Ajax update.

This is the code I am using:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#main > div:nth-child(6) > input:nth-child(6)')[0].click();
setTimeout(function() { document.querySelectorAll('#main > div:nth-child(6) > input:nth-child(8)')[0].click(); }, 1000);
```

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that the script jumps between two pages by the clicking. The first one works but the second .click() returns that the button I'm trying to .click() is undefined. So I thought I have a bad selector and copied it from Chrome dev tools. But the problem still persists. Someone suggested to put the .click() into the Ajax callback but I would also have to insert code that would insert this .click() to the now present button and it would go on forever.

Comment: Put the code that calls `.click()` in the AJAX callback, after it updates the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have left a lot out of your code snippet (also it would be nice to see it formatted). In your ajax call you should be putting this in your "success" block.

You want to trigger the click on the listener that already exists on the button. First you will bind your listener, then on the user action you will trigger the click.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'MyURL',
        contentType: 'YourContentType',
        type: 'GETorPOST',
        dataType: 'yourDataType'})
    .success(function (result) {
        $("#myButton").trigger("click");
        OR
        clickYourButtonFunction();
    })
    .error(function (xhr, status) {
        console.log(status);
    });
```